# Conditional Javascript for mobile

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, media-queries

I've been trying out various solutions to this problem for weeks now! :(

I would like my javascript to load conditionally based on the device width. This is so that my fixed menu div will scroll with the screen on desktop, and stay put on mobile/tablet.

Here is my script;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
function fixDiv() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 310)
    { 
    $('#Portfolio-Sidebar-Content-Web').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'margin-top': '20px'}); 
    }
  else
    {
    $('#Portfolio-Sidebar-Content-Web').css({'position': 'static', 'top': 'auto', 'margin-top': '0'});
    }
}
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
fix5iv();
}
});
</script>
```

I have tried adding;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
if ( $(window).width() > 480) {
function fixDiv() {
  SCRIPT FUNCTION
}
});
</script>
```

...and;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
if (matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 480px)').matches) {
function fixDiv() {
  SCRIPT FUNCTION
}
});
</script>
```

I have also tried @media queries using CSS to change the positioning of the div based on device width. This has no results whatsoever, it would seem that the javascript styling is !important, thus overriding any styling which I apply in my style sheet.

The javascript alterations that I have tried either disable or enable the script in both mobile/tablet and desktop. So my code works, sort of, but it would seem isn't detecting the device width correctly.

It did become apparent that my viewport setting could be interrupting the device width, producing the same results in any broswer;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1100"/>
```

However, even after disabling this snippet (completely removing it from the code), the same problems still occur.

Am I missing something obvious? is the solution non-existent?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JS to solve this issue. Just use a media query + proper meta tag. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/asimpson/edd53a02cdb1a2a1b28f) for what I'm talking about.